# What does metamodernism say about Eric Gans' ideas on "victimary thinking"?

Tags: postmodernism

Do Vermeulen and van den Akker's ideas on so called "metamodernism" have anything to say on Eric Gans' ideas of "victimary thinking"?

From wikipedia

> The prefix 'meta' here refers not to some reflective stance or
>   repeated rumination, but to Plato's metaxy, which intends a movement
>   between opposite poles as well as beyond

and

> In contrast to postmodernism, [Gans'] post-millennialism is distinguished by the rejection of victimary thinking and a turn to “non-victimary dialogue” that will “diminish […] the amount of resentment in the world.

I ask, just cos the phrases about post-millennialism, the sole ones I have encountered, quoted in the article, seem potentially problematic. As if we can reduce global ressentment by convincing the "victims" that their concerns can be negotiated away.

Comment: my only point being that society and culture seems to be such that the majority often find themselves ressenting either their own need to negotiate, or influence, or both

Comment: oh and marx, ha, "history is the history of class struggle" etc.